# After updating unity to last version 2019.2 i got some added Permissions in my game

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, android-security

I updated to last version of unity , when i tried to upload my game into google play first of all they didn't let me review it cause of READ-PHONE-STATE permission , i added to android manifest file this line

```
<uses-permission

   android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"

   tools:node="remove">
```

when i published this game for test i found that its asks too about Device & app history / Identity / Wifi connection information

for the connection permission maybe its okay cause i use gpgs but why it needs the other 2 permissions all what i did in this game is save game stats in a file and load them when i need to check levels etc .. , why unity auto add this permissions to my game do i need to remove them with same lines code as READ-PHONE-STATE , but thats not the right why to deal with that kind of toxic problem why it adds this permissions while i don't need them ????? help plz

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to delete UnityChannel folder in Plugins folder , so maybe the aar file of UnityChannel contain this permessions and when building it merged with other androidmanifest.xml files.